# How to load personal prolog.el only if system's one is outdated?

Tags: hooks, autoload

I need to use a version of `prolog.el` not older than 1.25, so I defined the function `maybe-reload-prolog-el`:

```
(defun maybe-reload-prolog-el ()
  (when (version< prolog-mode-version "1.25")
    (add-to-list
     'load-path
     (file-name-as-directory (concat my-lib-path "prolog-el")))
    (load-library "prolog"))))
```

...which adds the path to my personal copy of `prolog.el` to `load-path` (and then reloads `prolog`) if it detects that `prolog-mode-version` is too old <sup>1</sup>.

Then I put a call to `maybe-reload-prolog-el` in a hook I already had for `prolog-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'prolog-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    ;; ;; some keyboard settings, like
    ;; (local-set-key [f10] ...)
    ;; (local-set-key  [f9] ...)
    ;; ;; etc
    (maybe-reload-prolog-el)))
```

The main problem with this approach is that `prolog.el` is responsible for more than `prolog-mode`.  For example, it has the code for the autoloaded function `run-prolog`, which I use to run a Prolog sub-process in an Emacs buffer.  AFAICT, `prolog-mode-hook` does not get triggered when I run `run-prolog`, so I end up running an outdated version of it.

**Is there some way to trigger `maybe-reload-prolog-el` *right after* `prolog.el` is loaded, before any of its code gets executed?**

---

BTW, as currently written, `maybe-reload-prolog-el` can run only after `prolog.el` is loaded, because it relies on the variable `prolog-mode-version`, which is defined in `prolog.el`, to decide whether to load my local copy of `prolog.el`.  IOW, if I simply put the following code in my init file

```
(if (version< prolog-mode-version "1.25")
  (add-to-list
   'load-path
   (file-name-as-directory (concat my-lib-path "prolog-el"))))
```

...it fails with:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: prolog-mode-version
```

If there were some way to test the version of the default `prolog.el`'s version before loading it (let's call this method `PROLOG-OLDER-THAN-1.25-p`, then I would just put this in my init file:

```
(if (PROLOG-OLDER-THAN-1.25-p)
  (add-to-list
   'load-path
   (file-name-as-directory (concat my-lib-path "prolog-el"))))
```

Please let me know if there's a way to implement a `PROLOG-OLDER-THAN-1.25-p` that does not require `prolog.el` to be loaded.

---

Of course, I know that I can always use my copy of `prolog.el`, unconditionally.  IOW, I can just put this in my init file:

```
(add-to-list
 'load-path
 (file-name-as-directory (concat my-lib-path "prolog-el"))))
```

This approach works in the short-term, of course, but it requires more maintenance long-term.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Please let me know if what my `maybe-reload-prolog-el` function does is the best way to conditionally reload `prolog.el`.  I'm not too confident that `(load-library "prolog")` is the right thing to do here.</sup>

Comment: "a way to implement `PROLOG-OLDER-THAN-1.25-p` that does not require prolog.el to be loaded" - the only way would be to search the source code text.

Comment: You could try and inspect the data from the package manager package.el

Comment: @YoungFrog prolog.el is not (yet) an package.el package.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `eval-after-load` or `with-eval-after-load`?  E.g. something like this?

```el
(eval-after-load "prolog" '(maybe-reload-prolog-el))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check `emacs-major-version` instead of the version of prolog.el.