# Why do symbols become suddenly defined right after startup?

Tags: start-up

Below is an example of the situation described in the question's title, using the variable `prolog-mode-version` as test case.

If my Emacs init file consists of *just* the code shown below:

```
(defun show-pmv (hook-name)
  (let ((pmv (if (boundp 'prolog-mode-version)
                 prolog-mode-version
               "undefined")))
    (message "%s: prolog-mode-version: %s" hook-name pmv)))

(add-hook 'after-init-hook    (lambda () (show-pmv "after-init")))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (show-pmv "emacs-startup")))
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook  (lambda () (show-pmv "window-setup")))

(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")
```

...and I start up Emacs, my `*Messages*` buffer contains the following

```
after-init: prolog-mode-version: undefined
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
emacs-startup: prolog-mode-version: undefined
window-setup: prolog-mode-version: undefined
```

...but if, *right after startup*, I inspect the value of `prolog-mode-version` (using `C-h v`), I get a non-void value (`"1.22"`).

The variable `prolog-mode-version` is not an isolated case.  In fact, many other symbols defined in `prolog.el` seem to be available right after startup, even though my init file does not load/require this package.

I find this extremely confusing.

Why do symbols that were void during startup become suddenly defined *right after* startup?

Conversely, is there some way for my init file to access the value of `prolog-mode-version`?

([Related.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31086/882))

Comment: Are you using Emacs version 26.0.50? There is a new feature which autoloads libraries during completion, so your `C-h v` might be triggering the load. See also [Bug#25552](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25552#11).

Comment: Does anything change if, before your calls to `#'add-hook`, you put `(require 'prolog-mode)`?

Comment: @zck: no; the totality of my init file is what I show in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's autoloaded. Or rather, I should say that the library is autoloaded, so that the variable only starts existing once you've caused Emacs to actually load the library (usually by calling a function or using a macro from the library).

However, autoloading isn't available when processing the init files. Instead, explicitly load the library with `(require 'prolog)`.

Autoloading is a moderately complex subject, so I recommend reading section 15.5 of the Elisp manual. Actually, all of chapter 15 is quite interesting.

Comment: autoloading is available when processing init files, e.g., if you put `(run-prolog)` in your init file, the prolog library will be loaded.

Comment: The original post states that the behaviour was tested also in 'after init' so I don't think this answer actually explains anything. Or does it? I'd like to see a reply to npostavs' comment (wrt Emacs version) however.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols defined *only* in the `prolog` library will be bound only if that library has actually been loaded. You can establish *when* it is being loaded by invoking the debugger:

```el
(add-hook 'after-load-functions 'my-load-debug)

(defun my-load-debug (file)
  (when (string= "prolog" (file-name-base file))
    (debug)))
```

or just:

```el
(eval-after-load "prolog" '(debug))
```

If there are *autoload* definitions for the symbols, then they would be bound (without loading the `prolog` library), as soon as the appropriate `loaddefs.el` (or equivalent) file defining those autoloads has been loaded.

Note that `C-h v` and `C-h f` will indicate when a given variable or function is an autoload definition.