# How to re-load a package?

Tags: start-up, libraries, eval, load

The situation I have is this.  First, I run

```
(require 'prolog)
```

...which loads the system's default version of `prolog.el`, and makes the variable `prolog-mode-version` available.  It has value `"1.22"`.

Now, I know that my personal copy of this package, in `/path/to/my/own/private/prolog.el`, starts with

```
(defvar prolog-mode-version "1.25"
  "Prolog mode version number")
```

So I run

```
(load "/path/to/my/own/private/prolog.el")
```

...expecting that, after doing so, `prolog-mode-version` will now have value `"1.25"`.

This is not what happens, though: according to `describe-variable` at least, the value of `prolog-mode-version` is still `"1.22"`.

---

**What must I need to do to (re-)load `'prolog` from `/path/to/my/own/private/prolog.el`?**

Comment: `defvar`s (and `defcustom`s, which use `defvar`) can only be [defined once](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html). To re-evaluate a `defvar`, place point over it and `eval-defun` (`C-M-x`).

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: thanks!  How can I do what you describe programmatically?

Comment: Not easily. See: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-do-i-force-re-evaluation-of-a-defvar

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: Thanks again.  Come to think of it, I need to `eval` the whole file, since there's a ton of other `defvar`s in there...  I never expected this to be such a nightmare...

Comment: If you're running your own version of the package, why not stop using the system-provided one?

Comment: Why are you loading the built-in version of the package in the first place?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: I explain why here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31086/882

Comment: @Tyler: see here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31086/882

Comment: Is there ever a situation where you have a personal version of the package installed but *don't* want to use it? It would be easier to check for the presence of your custom version, and load it if present, and if it isn't present *then* load the built-in.

Comment: @Tyler: If the system version is more recent than my version, I'd prefer to use the system version.

Comment: Just use your local version. "Use system version if it's newer" sets you up for surprises--what if the system version breaks backward compatibility in some unexpected way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unload the system prolog mode first, this unbinds all its variables, so that the new `defvar` init-forms will take effect:

```el
(require 'prolog)
(when (version< prolog-mode-version "1.25")
  (unload-feature 'prolog)
  (load "/path/to/my/own/private/prolog.el"))
```

Note that `unload-feature` is not a commonly used function, so it's possible you may hit some bugs.  Most packages are not written with unloading in mind.  Glancing at prolog.el, I don't see anything that should be a problem though (examples of *potentially* "problematic" forms would be side-effecting top-level calls, apart from the usual `defun`, `defvar`, `defconst`, `defcustom`, etc).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the caveat "*Most packages are not written with unloading in mind.*"

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed that, although I had used `(require 'prolog)` in my original question, in your answer you used `(require 'prolog-mode)` instead.  Was there a particular reason for that change?

Comment: @kjo no, that was a mistake on my part, fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `unload-feature`, you could use this to check the version of the default package without actually loading the code:

```
(let ((version (with-temp-buffer
                 (insert-file (find-library-name "prolog"))
                 (re-search-forward "(defvar prolog-mode-version \"\\([^\"]+\\)")
                 (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))
  (if (< version 1.25)
      (load "/path/to/my/own/private/prolog.el")
    (require 'prolog)))
```